# Continuity of oscillating function

Tags: continuity

there an expression 
i had to show this function is continuos

$$
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
x\cdot \sin \frac1x,&x\neq 0
\\
0,&x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

while taking left hand limit or right hand

F(0-h) = $lt_{h→0}$ (0-h)(sin 1/(0-h))

in the next step i divided and multiplied sin function by 1/-h and i got answer 1 as  $lt_{x→o}$sin(x)/x  =1  Now that prove the function is discontinuous as Lhl ≠ limit at the point

Can anyone point where i am being wrong or what's wrong in my method.
The question provided it's own answer , I'm just asking what's wrong with my method

Comment: This is really difficult to read. Could you please re-format it?

Comment: I strongly feel that this question has been posted before on this site as well as others. But for continuity you may think of squeeze theorem to begin with.

Comment: @imranfat can you provide me with the link of the question

Comment: see https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-prove-that-the-function-xsin-1-x-is-continuous-at-x-0

Comment: or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274594/epsilon-delta-proof-that-fx-x-sin1-x-x-ne-0-is-continuous

Comment: The step where you "divided and multiplied sin function by 1/-h" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @EricWofsey  why? Isn't  limit(x→0)  sin(x)/x = 1.I don't get what's the problem there.